# Folder sharing disabled in macOS Catalina (10.15.3) and iOS/MacOS devices

Tags: macos-catalina, icloud

In MacOS Catalina they supposedly added the feature to be able to **share folders** in iCloud Drive like you do with files (see link below). However, on all my Apple devices/computer it is either missing or disabled. In my preferences *"Share Menu"* section, the *"Add People"* checkbox is greyed out.

[image: Greyed out]

I can't find anyone mentioning this issue on the internet. Thanks for the help!

(Btw, I did look at AskDifferent with no luck; I felt that this might be a more robust spot for a tricky question.)

https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-use-icloud-drive-folder-sharing-macos-and-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the article mentioned above was premature and only applied to a beta release. This feature was later released in an update.

Comment: Which update was this functionality actually added in?  Like you I can't find any information about it.